Extract JSON Variable Property in PowerShell and Expand Variable to Its Value
I have created a JSON file in PowerShell containing properties of related files.  When I retrieve the properties, I would like the variable extracted to expanded to its value.
The JSON file contains information to format and insert data into a created Excel file via Export-Excel.
My goal is to loop through the JSON file and pull in all of the information to create the spreadsheet.
Here is a snippet of the JSON file:
{
    "ClientMatters_Count": {
       "Var":   "$ClientMattersList",
       "File":  "D:\\TFS\\ProjectND\\ImportExport\\Import\\Export\\ClientMattersListCount.csv",
    },
    "DocTypes_Count": {
      "Var":   "$DocTypesList",
      "File":  "$DocTypesListCountCsv",
    }
}

When I extract the ClientMatters_Count.File it extracts the string and it works.  While this works, it is not ideal for me.
I would like to have the DocTypes_Counts.File variable expand to its value.
For example,
Defined in PowerShell:
$DocTypesListCountCsv = "D:\TFS\Project\ImportExport\Import\Export\DocTypeListCount.csv"

When I read the JSON file, 
ClientMatters.DocType_Counts.File gives me $DocTypesListCountCsv

I would like it to give me:
D:\TFS\Project\ImportExport\Import\Export\DocTypeListCount.csv

The *.Var properties are inserted into the Excel spreadsheet and their values are created at runtime.
$Nd_ClientMattersList.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

I have tried typecasting the variables and stripping the strings with no luck.
A suggested answer is this:
$ExcelConfig.DocTypes_Count.File

$Nd_DocTypesListCountCsv

Get-Variable -Name $ExcelConfig.DocTypes_Count.File -ValueOnly

Get-Variable: Cannot find a variable with the name '$Nd_DocTypesListCountCsv'.

---------- Update & Expand ----------------
To expand on the *.Var, it is an imported CSV file that I use to count doc types.
$DocTypesList = Import-Csv -Path $DocTypesListCsv




DocType
Active
Inactive




22-AP-331-OTHER
0
0


22-AP-331-PLEADING
0
0


23-AP-130-PLEADING
0
0


23-AP-246-PLEADING
0
0



This file gets updated when counting document types. It is then exported to: $DocTypesListCountCsv and an Excel file.
I would like to define the variable in the JSON file and have it expand to the imported CSV variable $DocTypesList.

You can use ExpandString Method to evaluate the variable expression stored in the string:
$DocTypesListCountCsv = "D:\TFS\Project\ImportExport\Import\Export\DocTypeListCount.csv"

$json = @'
{
    "ClientMatters_Count": {
       "Var":   "$ClientMattersList",
       "File":  "D:\\TFS\\ProjectND\\ImportExport\\Import\\Export\\ClientMattersListCount.csv"
    },
    "DocTypes_Count": {
      "Var":   "$DocTypesList",
      "File":  "$DocTypesListCountCsv"
    }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($json.DocTypes_Count.File)

As for your approach using Get-Variable, it's a valid option too but you need to trim the $ from the beginning of the string:
Get-Variable $json.DocTypes_Count.File.TrimStart('$') -ValueOnly


Thank you @Santiago.
The command provided me the clue to solving the issues:
Get-Variable $json.DocTypes_Count.File.TrimStart('$') -ValueOnly
